# how to turn pages in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard, shinydashboard

I am learning Shiny to build simple website, on my website I would like to post the information in each box(or other widget), I want to add the paging to it. That is, on page 1 there are box 1-4; and page 2 there are box 5-8; and page 3/4/5...On the bottom I can turning the page. Just like when we use google, we can turn to next/previous pages to view the result.

I have went through the examples on Shiny website, but I haven't found any examples contain this situation. Below is the code helps to understand what I am trying to do.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# ui
header <- dashboardHeader(title = "My App")
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()
body <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    # box1
    box(
      title = "Many boxes to display", width = 12, height = 250
    ),
    # box2
    box(
      title = "Many boxes to display", width = 12, height = 250
    ),
    # box3
    box(
      title = "Many boxes to display", width = 12, height = 250
    ),
    # box4
    box(
      title = "Many boxes to display", width = 12, height = 250
    ),
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

# server
server <- function(input, output) {}

# app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Does your navigation need to be at the bottom of the page? Because I know there a several options for top bar or sidebar navigation with several pages but I don't know if there are any for the bottom of the page.

Comment: Do you mean tabsetPanel and tabPanel? It is a bit different from what I am trying to do, I am trying to put all the things on one tab, when user scroll down they can turn to next page to see more things, or on some websites I see there is a "Load More" option, when clicked it shows more additional things. like this one:https://www.cnbc.com/economy/

Comment: In shinydashboard there is also tabItems() and in shiny there is navbarPage() but I'm afraid neither of the does exactly what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak the demonstration in this page to work for you
https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/tree/master/multiple-pages

1. If you want the paging to be sequential, you can use same next/prev buttons and change text to 1/10, 2/10 etc to make the user more informed about total number of pages.
2. If that' not an issue, you can dynamically generate a list of numbered buttons and link their actions to your pages, imitating a page turn